# WCF Server and Non .NET Client

Tags: java, c#, wcf

I have a WCF project, which consists of:

```
WCF Server
WCF Client
WCF Class Library
```

The class library is shared by the server and client and contains a Person object.  Therefore the client can do this:

```
public Person XMLToPerson()
{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client s1 = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    Person p = s1.GetPerson();
    return p;
}
```

What happens if you have a Java client that references the web service? Surely this is against interoperability?

Q1) What happens if you have a Java client? How can it accept a Person object?

Q2) Why does the web service return custom types instead of JSON/XML? If it returned JSON/XML, then the client could desterilize it any way it wanted?

This is the same for legacy web services (.asmx).  Fortunately all the web services I have developed in the past are used by .NET clients only so I do not need to think about this.  However, the question has always been at the back of my mind.

Comment: I gave you an answer below, but this question is so fundamental to how WCF works and why it exists that I think you could really benefit from spending some time with an intro to WCF tutorial, book, or video. There's got to be hundreds to choose from out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using BasicHttpBinding then what is sent between the server and the client is SOAP XML, not objects. You see custom types in .net because .net gives you a nice framework that abstracts away all the XML. This is important in WCF because WCF can also be used to work with other formats and protocols by changing or adding configuration (not by rewriting code). ASMX also uses SOAP but it doesn't have the flexibility WCF does.

You can run into incompatibility problems with different implementations of SOAP on different platforms, but I haven't seen that too often.

Comment: Thanks.  However, I don't believe this answers either of my questions.

Comment: Are you asking how do you consume SOAP from Java then?

Answer (score 0):

WCF exchanges information in SOAP format, so it is highly interoperable with other languages. Java clients can be Apache CXF to generate wrapper classes, for example,

http://adventuresinsoftware.com/blog/?p=481

You can also convert WCF to expose REST API, which is quite common at this moment.

Specifically to answer your questions. When you use VS to generate a service reference, the SOAP to object conversion is automatically handled by the generated wrapper classes (Apache CXF does the same for Java clients). You really should take a look at the generated classes to know how. Probably then you also know why nobody really wants to touch raw SOAP data, as XML is too verbose and you don't want to waste time on your own.

Comment: Thanks.  If you create the channel dynamically (rather than add Service Reference), then does this mean that SOAP is returned directly i.e. the framework will not deserialize the SOAP into an object for you?

Comment: @w0051977 nobody does that, but yes technically speaking if you connect in the raw way, you can see the SOAP messages directly.