# JSON not parsed into custom object

Tags: c#, json, web-services

Please see the AJAX below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="Javascript/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function GetData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "JSONExample.aspx/GetPerson",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "text",
            success: OnSuccess(),
            //async: false,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert('there was an error counting possibles')
            }
        });

        function OnSuccess() {
            return function (response) {
                alert(response);
                window.location.href("JSONExample.aspx?id=" + response);
            }
        }
        }
        GetData()
    </script>
```

and the server side code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SerializeAndDeserializeJSON
{
    //[Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
        public String Name;
        public int Age;
    }

    public partial class JSONExample : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((Request.QueryString["id"]== null)==false)
            {
                var json = Request.QueryString["id"];
                var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json); //person is null
            }
        }

        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static Person GetPerson()
        {
            Person p1 = new Person();
            p1.Name = "Ian";
            p1.Age=35;
            return p1;
        }
    }
}
```

In the page load the Person object values are as follows after the page load:

Name: null
Age: 0

The name should be Ian and the Age should be 35.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check your response is null, change dataType to json

Comment: Is the Json object invalid inside the OnSuccess function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Try setting dataType to `json` instead of `text`:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

And then send the javascript object as a JSON string in the `id` parameter:

```
window.location.href("JSONExample.aspx?id=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(response.d)));
```

Notice that we are using `response.d` here because ASP.NET WebMethods serialize the responses using this special property.

Also you probably want to use public properties instead of fields for your model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Some frameworks choke on fields.

Comment: Thanks.  However, this produces an error on the server side which says: "Could not cast or convert from System.String to SerializeAndDeserializeJSON.Person."

Comment: What's the value of the `id` parameter that you get on the server?

Comment: \"{\\\"d\\\":{\\\"__type\\\":\\\"SerializeAndDeserializeJSON.Person\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"Ian\\\",\\\"Age\\\":35}}\

Comment: OK, I see the problem. Use `dataType: 'json'` and then `JSON.stringify(response.d)`. I have updated my answer to reflect this change. The caveat is to use `response.d`.

Comment: Thanks.  That did it.

Comment: Are you able to answer my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41487328/wcf-server-and-non-net-client.  Same principle.  I want JSON returned by a WCF web service, however the .NET framework already desterilizes the JSON/XML behind the scenes.  Therefore the WCF web service returns the Person.